# Adding string values into dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add the name name of specific stocks along a "name" column of my data frame.

The dataframe consists of typical columns of a stock dataset: date, price, and so on. Finally there is the `"name"` column, which currently is just filled with the string "name" all the way down.

I have made a list of the tickers (stock names) both as a list and as a dataframe (whatever is easiest to use). There are 505 stocks.

*Each section (i.e. each stock's data) is 5314 rows long (as I have daily data this is the number of days).***

My goal is to somehow append this list of stick names to the "name" column that corresponds with each stock's section.

The dataframe is alphabetically sorted, so is my list of stock tickers.

I think I should do something like;
Append ticker 1 down 5314 rows
Append ticker 2 down the next 5314 rows.
.....
and so on.

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image: https://ibb.co/6Wv4W7y]

Ignore the change in column order for now. Not sure why they changed when I merged the files...

df

```
shareholders_equity tot_capital_risk working_capital name 
2676424 2317.0 NaN 3297.0 name 2676425 2317.0 NaN 3297.0 name 2676426 2317.0 NaN 3297.0 name 2676427 2317.0 NaN 3297.0 name 2676428 2317.0 NaN 3297.0 name
```

**EDIT:** I just found out that the different CSV files of individual stocks (and consequently the different sections) are of unequal length. Some are 5314 rows, some are 5311, others are 5315 etc. 
How can I solve it now?

Comment: are you able to supply a sample data set (5-10 rows) and your expected output?

Comment: This is what I want (note the name column):
https://ibb.co/WPyXnRp

This is what I have now (note the "name" column again):
https://ibb.co/JsbxrPB

Comment: can you post it as text so we can put it into an editor and see what works ? (normally, that's the accepted custom on SO, see how to ask a question :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```py
t=0
i=1
for index df.index.values:
     #set Name column of current row equal to the ticker in your ticker list at index t
     df.at[index, 'Name']=list_of_tickers[t]
     #skip to the next index of your ticker list when the number of iterations is a multiple of 5314
     if i%5314==0: 
        t+=1 #increase the index of the ticker name list by one
     i+=1
```

Comment: Seems reasonable!
But I get "'float' object has no attribute 'iloc'"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test before posting. It should work now @themli. I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.loc[df.index%5314 == 0, 'name'] = list_of_tickers
df['name'] = df['name'].ffill()
```

`ffill` replaces nan values with the first non-null value upwards